# xhtml call to servlet not returning response, not calling servlet

Tags: java, servlets, xhtml

I'm trying to call a servlet from a form. I have xhtml in a web app making a call to a servlet but the response from the servlet is not displaying.  The original xhtml displays after the submit button is pressed.  I tried different alternatives for the servlet response, but I get the same result each time.

xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:ejstreegrid="https://unfccc.int/nais/ejstreegrid"
xmlns:grid="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/gridcomp"
xmlns:nais="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/naiscomp">
<body>
<ui:composition template="/templateForm.xhtml">
<ui:define name="title">Some title</ui:define>
<ui:param name="currentPage" value="somepage.xhtml" />
<ui:define name="body">
<h2>the name to be added</h2><br/><br/>
<form action="someServlet" method="post">
<input type="text" name="someName" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</body> 
</html>
```

servlet in web app being called:

```
package netgui.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class someServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public someServlet() {
super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException   {
processRequest(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
processRequest(request, response);
}

private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

try {
response.getWriter().write("some response");
} catch (Exception e) {
logger.error(e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
response.getWriter().println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}}}
```

I also have a menu.xhtml that is calling the xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btn").click(function() {
$("#upload").click(); 
return false; 
}); 
});
</script>   
<ui:composition>
<div id="navigation_bar">
<ul id="topbarleft">
<c:choose>                  
<c:when test="${currentPage=='somepage.xhtml'}">
<li><b>Other (Please Specify) Two</b></li>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<li><h:outputLink value="somepage.jsf">
<h:outputText value="some page" />
</h:outputLink></li>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</ul>
</div>
</ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? Is there some special format for submitting a form to a servlet in jsf? with facelets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using templates in facelets while also calling a servlet with a form.

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"

<ui:composition template="/templateForm.xhtml">

<form action="someServlet" method="post">
```

The template has it's own h:form tag, so when I add another form to call the servlet, I end up with a form within a form which is not allowed.  So that was why my servlet was not being called.  I fixed it by removing the h:form tag from the template now my servlet is being called.

Comment: also in general calling a servlet from facelets is not a good idea